# Restore previous In-App Purchases in application programmatically after install or update?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

We are having the issue that the app we have has an In-App purchase that unlocks some content when it is paid.

The problem is that if you reinstall the app or update it, it will be reinstalled without the unlocked content. The customer will have to go through the buying process again and it will then tell them that they already have purchased the content. Is there any way to avoid this issue so that automatically the purchased content is provided if you have already paid for it?

We have tried asking the user for his Apple ID during launch of the app and retrieve his previous payments from that, but Apple disapproves of the practice.

I may be looking at this at a different, unconventional angle but I am really looking for a widely accepted approach for this kind of thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does updating the app delete their existing purchases? I can understand why deleting the app would do as that removes all their documents, but when they update the app it should keep all the data, including any data you've stored about in-app purchases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "Restore Purchases" button calling restoreCompletedTransactions on SKPaymentQueue is the way to go-

We considered checking this call automatically on start, or before giving the user a price for the in-app update, but the prompt for user iTunes details which appears makes this impractical, so the button is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

For that you should simply call `restoreCompletedTransactions` of the `SKPaymentQueue` on startup. That's the way apple suggests.

Comment: This was what we tried but this is exactly what Apple didn't approve of as this prompts the user for his Apple ID.

Comment: Hmm, we do that in our apps, but maybe just add a 'restore purchases' button somewhere?